# Conversion date when storing in a table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a field date in `DataTable`

```
jeudi 12 mars 2015
vendredi 13 mars 2015
samedi 14 mars 2015
```

I need to store it in a table in sql server  `test` which have a column `datedes` type `date`

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [test] ([Datedes]) VALUES('" + dt.Rows[i][j] + "')", con);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> The code above always return error in conversion date.

how to resolve it ?

Comment: What is the type of that field in `dt`? And probably you don't need single quotes in your `VALUES` part.

Comment: But you try to insert that `string` to your `Datedes` column which is `date`. You see what is wrong exactly, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

- Convert your `rows[i][j]` to a `DateTime`
- use properly **parametrized** query in ADO.NET to insert your date

Code something like this:

```
// this might not work right now - you need to adapt this to that
// you can convert your strings like 'vendredi 13 mars 2015' to a
// valid "DateTime" object
DateTime dateTimeFromRow = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][j]);

// set up your DB connection string    
string connectionString = "....";

// define your insert query with PARAMETERS
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [test]([Datedes]) VALUES(@DateDes);";

// use "using" blocks to properly dispose of connection and command    
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn)
{
    //  define and set value for parameter
    command.Parameters.Add("@DateDes", SqlDbType.Date);
    command.Parameters["@DateDes"].Value = dateTimeFromRow;

    // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection        
    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you try to insert a `string` to your `date` type table column which is wrong obviously.

Depending on what you are doing;

- Change your `date` typed column to `nvarchar` and insert that string
- Parse your string to `DateTime` and insert that value with [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

For first option, just change your column type to `nvarchar`.

For second option, you need parse your string with `fr-FR` culture (if it is not your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and pass this value directly.

```
var s = "samedi 14 mars 2015";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));

using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [test] ([Datedes]) VALUES(@date)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dt;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is you try to parse data type string to datetime. And from your information the datetime format is not legal to parse. I suggest you to create another string type's field to store 'jeudi' 'vendredi' or 'samedi'.

Use to cut string :

```
        var targetString = "jeudi 12 mars 2015";
        var resultString = "";
        int index;

        foreach (var item in targetString)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out index) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ToString()))
            {
                resultString = targetString.Substring(index);
            }
        }
//resultString == "12 mars 2015"
```

Afterthat use :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [test] ([Datedes]) VALUES("@date")", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@date, resultString);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

***Do not append string like you do because it's not secure.***